# Cannot login to server with Basic Authorization and cURL. (User/pass + certificate)

Tags: php, web-services, curl, authorization

I am trying to access a server and its data from my own application. To log in I need a username and password plus a certificate, which I have. My problem is that I am apparently sending this information wrong, because I keep getting a 401. I should be able to, on this page, get some HAL+JSON data from this server after login. It is posted a field from a previous page and should submit that to the server to get the data.

Here is my code:

```
$username = 'foo';
$password = 'bar';
$auth_token = $username . '-' . $password;

$url = 'https://data.service.com'.$_POST['url'].'?callback=?';
$ch = curl_init($url); 
/* Upon receiving the right certificate 
*  I should have a cookie with this information. 
*/
$data_string = array('cert_url' => 'https://data.service.com/cert/2364o872ogfglsgw8ogiblsjy');    
/* That hash at the end corresponds to the Public Key ID 
*  in the certificate. No idea how to retrieve this, 
*  or if I need to do it to login
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(   
      'Accept: application/javascript',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *',                                                                       
      'Content-Type: application/javascript',
      "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($username.":".$password)
   ));  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, true);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);                                                                                                            
$result = curl_exec($ch);  
if(curl_exec($ch) === false){
      echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
      print_r(error_get_last());
} else {
      echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($result, true); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php#98164

Try to not use

```
"Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($username.":".$password)
```

Or let curl choose an auth method, try

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
```

For a case that curl didn't like the ssl cert on the remote server try this:

```
curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false ); 
curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST , false );
```

P.S. Are you sure CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER should be false in your case?

Comment: No not entirely sure but for the moment I have set it to `true` and changed `VERIFYPEER`/`VERIFYHOST` also. Now I have a 400.

Comment: 400 much worse than 401. Get it back and play with CURLAUTH_ANY and base64

Comment: I can see in the Authorization Basic header that the `base64_encode($username)` is correct. Though not the password. So I'm looking at why that is, since the password is definitely the right one.

Comment: I think "Authorization: Basic " header line is unnecessary when CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH is used. It's safe to use plain user:password with ssl. So drop this "Authorization" header line and use CURLAUTH_ANY to be clear.

Comment: Well I'm getting an 2200 Authentication Error instead from the server, so that's better, I guess. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I added the header "Authorization: Basic" with the base64 encoding and got in! Whoo! Thanks again! Wouldn't have done it without your pointers.